# Various View Models Structure - How to create view models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and readings it's tutorials for implementation. 
I got to know about 2 different ways of writing view models in early chapters. I just need to know what is the difference between them.

[image]

I tried to figure out myself but may be not picking rights words.
Pdf i am refering to is [Knockout PDF](http://files.cnblogs.com/files/artech/knockout.pdf)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Knockout. You are asking for the difference between an "object literal" and an object created with a "class constructor". Both can be view models. It's just two different ways of creating the same thing.

Comment: @CrimsonChris thanks for update. I able to update myViewModel.personName to a new value from browser console like myViewModel.personName('sahil'), but how to update AppViewModel.firstname property? Actually i want to check the responsiveness towards UI using these two approach.

Comment: There's no difference. You need to go read about Javascript class constructors.

Comment: Ok @CrimsonChris let me go through that

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to create objects in javascript. The first one you're showing in your question is a literal. Another one is defining a constructor and invoking itt to get the object.

Yor AppViewModel is a constructor. If you need to use an instance of it as your viewmodel, you have to invoke the constructor, like this:

```
var vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

*BTW, your `fullName` computed observable is incomplete. It's missing closing curly brakects, the second parameter, and closing parenthesis: `}, self);`*